# No SCSI Drive detected - is the cable to long (4m)?

Tags: cable, scsi

I have a LSI20320IE controller ( here are the [Specifications](https://www.quantelectronic.de/Server-und-Workstation/Zubehoer/SCSI--und-Raidcontroller/HP-SC11Xe-U320-SCSI-Controller-PCIe-x4-LSI20320IE-439946-001-i133_27377.htm) ) in an PCI-express slot and a LTO3 Ultrium HP TAPEDRIVE under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a DELL OPTIPLEX 9020 MT ( [Manual](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/optiplex-9020-desktop_owners-manual2_en-us.pdf) ). I have a 4 meters VHDCI(Male)-HD68(male) cable to connect each other.

I can not see the Drive by running the command `lsscsi`. But when I use a SCSI controller Adaptec  19160 (in a PCI slot)  with a short 1 Meter cable (50pin HD50  to HD68 SCSI) then I can see the HP Drive and works fine. I am sure the LSI20320IE controller works because is new. Could be the 4m cable too long? What are the maximal length for SCSI-3 device cables? [Parallel-SCSI-Overview](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Computer_System_Interface#Ultra-320_(2002)) Do I interpret this correclty, that the cable should be under 3 meters?

THanks a lot for finding the reason why it will not work with the PCI-express SCSI controller.

Comment: Take a look at [SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) under "SCSI interfaces". It says 12m maximum. Presuming the cable has no problem, you need to confirm the termination at the controller and device. This becomes more important at longer cable lengths. Also, confirm the controller is compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, some systems will display available SCSI devices on system boot or in the BIOS menus. That would be a better basic check.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it the cable as the termination is ok and at boot time I can see the controller. I have ordered a 3ft (about 1m) cable. Then I will see